# Django formview form_valid, form has no attribute `instance`

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form view using the `FormView` class. It works fine displaying the post form but when posting the data `form_valid` function is called and here I get an error:

`AttributeError: 'GameForm' object has no attribute 'instance'`

As I can understand the form object passed in the form_valid method doesn't contain an instance but [examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) show that it is possible.. What am i missing?

#### views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import (ListView, DetailView)
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from .models import Game
from .forms import GameForm


# ... Other views

class GameCreateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'games/game_form.html'
    form_class = GameForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

#### forms.py

```py
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Title'}),
                           label="Spel naam")
    description = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                  widget=forms.Textarea)
    materials = forms.CharField(required=False,
                                widget=forms.Textarea)
    duration_min = forms.IntegerField(required=False, label="Min. tijd")
    duration_max = forms.IntegerField(required=False, label="Max. tijd")
    group_size_min = forms.IntegerField(required=False, label="Min. aantal personen")
    group_size_max = forms.IntegerField(required=False, label="Max. aantal personen")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'name',
            Row(
                Column('duration_min', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                Column('duration_max', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            Row(
                Column('group_size_min', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                Column('group_size_max', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
                css_class='form-row'
            ),
            'description',
            'materials',

            Submit('submit', 'Post')
        )
```

#### Website log

```
AttributeError at /game/new/
'GameForm' object has no attribute 'instance'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/new/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'GameForm' object has no attribute 'instance'
```

Django version = 3.1.3

Thanks in advance!

**Edit** Added forms.py

Comment: Please show the full traceback, it makes it easier to see where the error is coming from. It would be a good idea to include `GameForm` in your question as well. I suspect that you're using `forms.Form` instead of `forms.ModelForm`. If you are creating a new instance, then `CreateView` is probably more suitable than `FormView`.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair I will look into the CreateView rather then the FormView for this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me in my project.

```
class GameCreateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'games/game_form.html'
    form_class = GameForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(GameCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```